# ipywidgets Widget - Date picker - issue with Mozilla Firefox

Tags: jupyter-notebook, datepicker, widget, ipywidgets

When I use Firefox and I click on the x next to the Date picker I get the following error message:

This is not happening with Chrome, and it should work also in Firefox by reading the web official web page, can you please help?
[image]

here the code:

```
from ipywidgets import DatePicker, FloatText,HBox, interactive_output, Text
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

ddecW = DatePicker(value=datetime.date.today() + relativedelta(months=2, day=1))
dobW = DatePicker(value=datetime.date.today() + relativedelta(years=-18))
etaW = FloatText(description='Età')


ui = HBox([ddecW, dobW, etaW])


def f(end, start, age):
    etaW.value = round((end - start).days/365.25, 1)

out = interactive_output(f, {'end': ddecW, 'start': dobW, 'age': etaW})

display(ui, out)
```

Answer (score 0):

The function is trying to calculate the difference between a `date` and a `None`, hence the error message. What should your output widget show in that case? 0?

Also because you included the `etaW` widget as part of the `interactive_output` call, when you set `eta.value` this will trigger `f` again, causing a recursion loop. A better approach would be the one below, or I would avoid using `interactive_output`, and just use `observe` functions.

```py
from ipywidgets import DatePicker, FloatText,HBox, interactive_output, Text
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import numpy as np

ddecW = DatePicker(value=datetime.date.today() + relativedelta(months=2, day=1))
dobW = DatePicker(value=datetime.date.today() + relativedelta(years=-18))
etaW = FloatText(description='Età')


ui = HBox([ddecW, dobW])


def f(end, start):
    val = round((end - start).days/365.25, 1)
    print(f'Delta is {val}')

out = interactive_output(f, {'end': ddecW, 'start': dobW,})

display(ui, out)
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much however if i click on the x next to the box I still receive an error message using Firefox, this is not happening on Chrome

Comment: Please post the error message and update your code to show exactly what is running and the resulting error